# Colocar un contenido por defecto en layout de JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Estoy intentado crear vistas usando un `layout` en [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), este es mi `layout`:

**/WEB-INF/tags/layouts/layout.tag**

```
<%@tag description="Layout de las paginas" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="title" fragment="true" %>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<title> 
    <jsp:invoke fragment="title" />
</title>
</head>

<jsp:doBody></jsp:doBody>

</html>
```

y lo uso en mis vistas así:

```
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/layouts" %>
<t:layout>
    <jsp:attribute name="title"> Página principal </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        Hola, Esta es la página principal
    </jsp:body>
 </t:layout>
```

mi pregunta es si yo no proporciono en mi vista el j`sp:attribute` así:

```
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/layouts" %>
<t:layout>
    <jsp:body>
        Hola, Esta es la página principal
    </jsp:body>
</t:layout>
```

en el title de la pagina aparece

> localhost:8000/homepage

¿Hay alguna forma de colocar un contenido por defecto en el `Layout` cuando el `fragment title` no es proporcionado ?